# Multisite list all pages in site

Tags: multisite

I have a WP Multisite that contains 3 sites - sites 1, 2, 3

Site 1 and 2 are just one page but site 3 has multi pages inside.

I would like to show a navigation on the top of each site to the other sites.

I would also like to show the child pages in site 3 on every page.

I'm using this code here to create the nav for all the sites.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<?php

  $the_blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
  $bcount = get_blog_count();

  global $wpdb;
  $blogs = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->blogs WHERE spam = '0' AND deleted = '0' and archived = '0' and public='1'",13, 'stack overflow' ) );

  echo ( $blogs->blogname );

  if ( !empty( $blogs ) ) {

?>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="portalHome">
      <a href="dashboard.html">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right chervonMobNav"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
<?php

  foreach ( $blogs as $blog ) {
    $details = get_blog_details( $blog->blog_id );

      if ( $details != false ) {
        $addr = $details->siteurl;
        $name = $details->blogname;
        $id = $details->blog_id;

        // echo $name ." is blog ". $id." / ";

        if ( !( ( $blog->blog_id == 2 ) && ( $show_main != 1 ) ) ) {
          $class = ( $blog->blog_id == get_current_blog_id() ) ? ' current-site' : '';

?>
    <li class="menu-item<?php echo $class; ?>" >
      <a href="<?php echo $addr; ?>"><?php echo $name;?> <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right chervonMobNav"></i></a>
<?php

         if ( $blog->blog_id == 4 ) {

            echo 'here';
            //show the nav for blog 4

            $pages_args = array(
              'title_li' => '',
              'depth' => 0
            );

            wp_list_pages( $pages_args );

         }

?>
    </li>
<?php
        }
      }
    }
?>
  </ul>
<?php
  }
?>
</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

The problem here is it only shows the pages in site 3 when I click that link and go it that site.

I want the nav to show the pages in site 3 when I'm on site 1 and site 2

So the nav in each site should look somneting like.

```
Site One | Site Two | Site Three
                        Site Three - page 1
                        Site Three - page 2
                        Site Three - page 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You did a good job writing your own query to get all the sites/blogs, but there's also a special WordPress function you can use: [`wp_get_sites()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_sites)

If you want to get content from another site/blog you have to switch first with [`switch_to_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog) to make sure your query will run within the right context. (And don't forget to switch back to normal with [`restore_current_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/restore_current_blog) afterwards!)

Having that said, I updated your snippet accordingly, so you can give it a try:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="portalHome">
      <a href="dashboard.html">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right chervonMobNav"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
<?php

  $args = array(
    'public' => 1 // limit to public sites
  );
  $sites = wp_get_sites( $args );
  $current = get_current_blog_id(); // current blog id

  foreach ( $sites as $site ) :

    $site_meta = get_blog_details( $site['blog_id'] );
    $current_class = $site['blog_id'] == $current ? ' current' : ''; // check for current site

    echo '<li class="menu-item' . $current_class .'" >';
    echo '<a href="' . $site_meta->siteurl . '">' . $site_meta->blogname . ' <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right chervonMobNav"></i></a>';

      if ( $site['blog_id'] == 4 ) : // check for special site
        switch_to_blog( 4 ); // now switch to this site

          $pages_args = array(
            'title_li' => '',
            'depth' => 0
          );
          echo '<ul>';
          wp_list_pages( $pages_args );
          echo '</ul>';

        restore_current_blog(); // switch back to normal
      endif;

    echo '</li>';

  endforeach;

?>
  </ul>
</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```